# Unit testing an ExceptionHandler class

Tags: java, junit5

I’m trying write a unit test for an ExceptionHandler class but I’m not 100% sure how to go about it. I’m struggling to work out how do I go about setting up the MethodArgumentNotValidException class with an error list?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class InputExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static final String INVALID_CHARACTER_MESSAGE = "Fields contain invalid characters:";

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                  HttpStatus status,
                                                                  WebRequest request) {

        final List<String> errorList = getErrorList(ex);
        final StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder(popFirstError(errorList));
        if(errorMessage.toString().contains(INVALID_CHARACTER_MESSAGE)) {
            combineDuplicateErrorMessage(errorList, errorMessage);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).body(makeBankDetailsValidationModel(errorMessage.toString()));
    }

    private BankDetailsValidationModel makeBankDetailsValidationModel(String validationErrorDescription){
        return new BankDetailsValidationModel(false, false, validationErrorDescription, "");
    }

    private StringBuilder combineDuplicateErrorMessage(List<String> errorList, StringBuilder errorMessage) {
        return errorList.stream()
                .filter(value -> value.contains(INVALID_CHARACTER_MESSAGE))
                .findFirst()
                .map(value -> errorMessage.append(", ").append(value.substring(35)))
                .orElse(null);
    }

    private String popFirstError(List<String> errorMessages) {
        final String message = errorMessages.get(0);
        errorMessages.remove(0);
        return message;
    }

    private List<String> getErrorList(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        return ex.getBindingResult()
                .getAllErrors()
                .stream()
                .map(ObjectError::getDefaultMessage)
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only testing your handler and not the invocation (that's Sping's job) why not just using a mock-Exception.

This way you could mock whatever properties your Exception needs to cover all the paths without having to com up with ways to create the Exception in first place...